# настройки Nginx

Tags: nginx, symfony, vps

Дилема у меня с настройками nginx + symfony. Стоuт php7.4-fpm u nginx 1.14.

запускаю я на 127.0.0.1:8000 сервер, перехожу по адресу 127.0.0.1:8000/ все работает нормально и хорошо.

Но стоит мне зайти на сайт допустим по доменному имени test.ru/ то некоторые функции не работают, если быть точным, то не работает shell_exec() функция.

Если я введу в адресной строке test.ru:8000/ все работает и команды которые ввожу в shell_exec() выполняются 100%

НАСТРОЙКИ NGINX название и папку убрал в целях так сказать безопасности )))

```
 server{
    server_name test.ru;
    root /home/user/project_symfony/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/(index_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
     }
     location ~ \.php$ {
     return 404;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Comment: Сервер чего вы запускаете на 8000 порту?

Comment: symfony если так не было понятно.